# How to sort a Collection<T> in-place?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have a generic collection:

```
public Items : Collection<Object>
{
   protected override void InsertItem(int index, Object item)
   {
      base.InsertItem(index, item);
      ...
   }

   protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
   {
      base.RemoveItem(index);
      ...
   }

   protected override void SetItem(int index, Object item)
   {
      base.SetItem(index, item);
      ...
   }

   protected override void ClearItems()
   {
      base.ClearItems();
      ...
   }
```

Now I need a way to sort this collection in-place.

### Bonus Chatter

I tried converting my class to use `List<T>` rather than `Collection<T>` (since `Collection<T>` doesn't support the concept of an order). That then allowed calling the `Sort` method:

```
this.Items.Sort(SortCompareCallback);

protected virtual int SortCompareCallback(Object x, Object y)
{
   return OnCompareItems(new SortCompareEventArgs(x, y, this.sortColumnIndex, direction));
}
```

But then I lose the virtual methods when the list is modified.

I thought about using Linq, but the problem with that is:

- I don't know how to call a callback from a Linq expression
- Linq doesn't sort a collection, it can only return a new one

How can I sort a generic `Collection<T>`?

Comment: after you load the List<T> you can call the Sort method on that ..it works.. what are you talking about..?

Comment: There are **144!** answers waiting for you to accept them

Comment: What is your actual implementation of the collection?  Is it an array, list, dictionary, set, some complex nested structure, what?  You need to sort that underlying data to expose a sort method, and you need to show us what that is before we can comment on how it might be done.

Comment: @Servy the actual implementation of the collection is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`

Comment: @gdoron Should i accept answers that don't answer the question, or should i continue to wait for a valid answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't need to have the virtual overrides called during the sorting, you should be able to do something like this:

```
class SortableCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;

    public SortableCollection() : this(new List<T>()) {}
    public SortableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }
    public void Sort() { _list.Sort(); }
}
```

Or this:

```
class SortableCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    public SortableCollection() : this(new List<T>()) {}
    public SortableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) {}
    public void Sort() { ((List<T>)Items).Sort(); }
}
```

Comment: This answer is the best, but i notice that `Collection<T>` already has a `protected IList<T> Items { get; }` property. Can eliminate the private `_list`, casting the returne `IList<T>` to a `List<T>` and call sort on that.

Comment: The Sort method is a member of the `List<T>` class, so you'd have to cast the return value of the protected property; I'll edit the code to reflect that possibility.  The documentation for "Items" says it "get an IList<T> wrapper around the Collection<T>." but that's not true; it actually exposes the IList that the collection wraps.

Comment: But poking through the reflector, i can see that `Collection<T>` is, in fact, creating a `List<T>`. Now, that *is* a private implementation detail subject to change at any time. But that's why your code can be used - you ***know*** that `Items` returns a `List<T>` because you gave it to the collection in the first place.

Comment: Ok... I'm happier. After looking at this post: [link](http://www.shirmanov.com/2011/03/various-ways-to-sort-list-of-objects-by.html) and in particular the comparison delegate along with this answer of casting the collection `Items` to `List<T>` I was able to sort in place. For me the line of code looked like this: `((List<MyItem>)Items).Sort((left, right) => string.Compare(left.Text, right.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCulture));`

Answer (score 2):

`Collection<T>` has an indexer. If you really want to sort the items in place, you can implement whatever sorting algorithm you prefer using the indexer. Here's an example that, with the proper Collection, can take O(N^3)...

```
void SortInPlace(Collection<T> col)
{
    for(int i=0; i<col.Count - 1; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j<col.Count; j++)
            if(col[i] < col[j]) // This won't compile, but you get the jist
                Swap col[i] and col[j]
}
```

You can implement one of the O(NlogN) algorithms to get an O(N^2logN) sort performance if your collection only offers O(N) item access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SortedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) (which also implements `ICollection<T>`, so you can treat it like a collection if you want to).

Comment: SortedSet<T> is the way to go because SortedList<TKey, TValue> is basically a dictionary. Also the T items must implement IComparable. But if that works, it is the most optimal approach.

Comment: @Dmitry: A set can only have one element of a given value (in general, not sure about the .NET implementation).  So if you put integers 1, 2, 2, 3 into a set, the set would contain {1, 2, 3} but if you put them into a list, the list would contain {1, 2, 2, 3}.  The semantics (in set theory... again not sure how .NET implemented it) are different between a set and a list.

Comment: I am just saying that SortedList<T> does not exist in .NET unless you implement it yourself. There is a SortedList<TKey, TValue> which is a more memory efficient version of SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>. SortedSet<T> is the closest available collection but it does not allow duplicates, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can sort a collection try this:

```
public ICollection<T> getSortedData(ICollection<T> collection, string property, string direction)
{
    switch (direction.Trim())
    {
        case "asc":
            collection = ((from n in collection
                           orderby
                           n.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(n, null)
                           select n).ToList<T>()) as ICollection<T>;
        break;
        case "desc":
            collection = ((from n in collection
                           orderby
                           n.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(n, null)
                           descending
                           select n).ToList<T>()) as ICollection<T>;
        break;
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i needed that badly. I have implemented it in extension notation with IEnumerable<T>, also for multiple string[] properties within a  loop with ThanBy.

Comment: This isn't in-place sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sortable list with content change notification, you should look at [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList.Adapter(yourCollection)` and sort it as an array.